# Run android project from a Flutter project with unsound null safety

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, dart-null-safety

After sound null safety has arrived, projects that still have dependencies that have not upgraded to null safety yet, can still be run using `--no-sound-null-safety` flag through the Flutter command.

But now I am trying to run the app through the `android` project. The reason why I am trying to do this way is to allow me to debug a native Flutter plugin. I open the folder `android` on Android Studio and when I try to run the project I receive an error:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:
```

If I was running through the Flutter command, the flag I mentioned would work here. But how do I set this flag when running the `android` project through Android Studio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Change your edit configurations.

   [image]
2. Add the flag `--no-sound-null-safety`

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

After searching a little more I found the solution to this problem. You do not need to run the project through Android Studio, you can run it with the Flutter command and then attach the debugger using Android Studio.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58760445/8633918